# office365, send mail use graph API, it usually fail

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365

when I send mail use graph API(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/***@***.onmicrosoft.com/sendMail) it usually fail。
the Http request is success，but the mail Delivery failed.

it returns erros under:

`Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
***@***.com.cn
Your message wasn't delivered because the recipient's email provider rejected it.

Diagnostic information for administrators:
Generating server: PUZPR03MB7209.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com
***@***.com.cn
Remote server returned '550 5.7.708 Service unavailable. Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP. For more information please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=526653 AS(7230) [KL1PR03MB5489.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com 2023-11-23T02:13:08.506Z 08DBEB7A30B986E6]'
Original message headers:
Received: from PUZPR03MB7209.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::2fc4:6115:7f4e:9337]) by PUZPR03MB7209.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com ([fe80::2fc4:6115:7f4e:9337%4]) with mapi id 15.20.7025.017; Thu, 23 Nov 2023 02:13:08 +0000 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/plain Date: Thu, 23 Nov 2023 02:13:08 +0000 Message-ID: PUZPR03MB7209A2AB62437072A83D2976EEB9A@PUZPR03MB7209.apcprd03.prod.outlook.com Subject: =?gb2312?B?suLK1NPKvP40?=`

on the same time, I send mail on outlook website, it successed.

or I use EWS API to send mail it also successed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an API problem your issue is that one of the IPAddreses that is being included in one of the mail headers is on a Black list eg you can check the RBL's using something like https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx?AG=GBL&gclid=CjwKCAiA9ourBhAVEiwA3L5RFp8f5W6PzOVHpQ8GNvyaKaMof3UtCW5u_G8wX9imdQApLe76XM9X4xoCbQIQAvD_BwE.

You probably need to dump the full header of the Message you may find what's getting put in X-Originating-Ip: is the problem. To solve it you might want to consider hosting your App on Azure (or AWS) to ensure you have a clean Ip path. If you want to validate if it really is that Graph that is the issue try sending a message to same address using the Graph Explorer.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. And I try sending a message to same address using the Graph Explorer, it has the same problem.

Comment: 5.7.708 Access denied, traffic not accepted from this IP This error can happen when you are trying out a Microsoft 365 trial tenant. If you receive this error before you can purchase licenses, contact support to request an exception for the low reputation IP address until you're able to purchase licenses.  I got the message on 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/ndr/fix-error-code-5-7-700-through-5-7-750, this should be the reseaon。